# Confidence Interval for a Chi-Square

Tags: r, statistics

How can I calculate a confidence interval for a chi-square in R?

Is there a function like `chisq.test()` ?

Comment: Please provide more context, such as the platform you're using, the documentation you've consulted, etc.

Answer (score 8):

There is no confidence interval for a chi-square test (you're just checking to see if the first categorical and the second categorical variable are independent), but you can do a confidence interval for the difference in proportions, like this.

Say you have some data where 30% of the first group report success, while 70% of a second group report success:

```
row1 <- c(70,30)
row2 <- c(30,70)
my.table <- rbind(row1,row2)
```

Now you have data in contingency table:

```
> my.table
     [,1] [,2]
row1   70   30
row2   30   70
```

Which you can run `chisq.test` on, and clearly those two proportions are significantly different so the categorical variables must be independent:

```
> chisq.test(my.table)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  my.table
X-squared = 30.42, df = 1, p-value = 3.479e-08
```

If you do `prop.test` you find that you are 95% confident the difference between the proportions is somewhere between 26.29% and 53.70%, which makes sense, because the actual difference between the two observed proportions is 70%-30%=40%:

```
> prop.test(x=c(70,30),n=c(100,100))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(70, 30) out of c(100, 100)
X-squared = 30.42, df = 1, p-value = 3.479e-08
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2629798 0.5370202
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
   0.7    0.3
```

Answer (score 5):

An addition to @mysteRious' nice answer: If you have a `2x2` contingency matrix, you could use `fisher.test` instead of `prop.test` to test for differences in the *ratio* of proportions instead of the *difference* of ratios. In Fisher's exact test the null hypothesis corresponds to an odds-ratio (OR) = 1.

Using @mysteRious' sample data

```
ft <- fisher.test(my.table)
ft
#
#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
#
#data:  my.table
#p-value = 2.31e-08
#alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#95 percent confidence interval:
#  2.851947 10.440153
#sample estimates:
#odds ratio
#  5.392849
```

Confidence intervals for the OR are then given in `fit$conf.int`

```
ft$conf.int
#[1]  2.851947 10.440153
#attr(,"conf.level")
#[1] 0.95
```

To confirm, we manually calculate the OR

```
OR <- Reduce("/", my.table[, 1] / my.table[, 2])
OR
#[1] 5.444444
```